# Change the color of Marker Symbol in Google maps - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot a set of lat longs in python using Google API. I have used the gmaps package. I have used the following code and created the map.

```
starbucks_df = starbucks_df[['ref_lat', 'ref_long']]
kfc_df = kfc_df[['ref_lat', 'ref_long']]

starbucks_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
    starbucks_df, fill_color="red",
    stroke_color="red", scale=5
)

kfc_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
    kfc_df, fill_color="black",
    stroke_color="black", scale=2
)


plant_locations = tuples_all_calls
info_box_template = """
<dl>
<dt>x</dt><dd>{x}</dd>
<dt>y</dt><dd>{y}</dd>
</dl>
"""
plant_info = [info_box_template.format(**plant) for plant in list1]

marker_layer = gmaps.marker_layer(plant_locations, info_box_content=plant_info, display_info_box=False)

fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(starbucks_layer)
fig.add_layer(kfc_layer)
fig.add_layer(marker_layer)
fig
```

[image]

Now I want to do the following options

1. Change the color of the marker symbol which is red currently
2. Reduce / Increase the size of the marker symbol

Is it possible to do both of these in gmaps? Can anybody help me in doing this? Is there any other packages which is available in python, that allows me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Markers and symbols](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#markers-and-symbols):

> Markers are currently limited to the Google maps style drop icon. If you need to draw more complex shape on maps, use the symbol_layer function. Symbols represent each latitude, longitude pair with a circle whose colour and size you can customize.